# Modified Kaprekar Numbers | Hackerrank

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

A modified Kaprekar number is a positive whole number *n* with *d* digits, such that when we split its square into two pieces - a right hand piece *r* with *d* digits and a left hand piece *l* that contains the remaining *d* or *d-1* digits, the sum of the pieces is equal to the original number (i.e. *l* + *r* = *n* ).

Note: r may have leading zeros.

Here's an explanation from Wikipedia about the ORIGINAL Kaprekar Number (spot the difference!): In mathematics, a Kaprekar number for a given base is a non-negative integer, the representation of whose square in that base can be split into two parts that add up to the original number again. For instance, 45 is a Kaprekar number, because 45² = 2025 and 20+25 = 45.

**The Task**

You are given the two positive integers *p* and *q* , where *p* is lower than *q* . Write a program to determine how many Kaprekar numbers are there in the range between  and  (both inclusive) and display them all.

```
void kaprekarNumbers(int p, int q) {
int flag=0,cpy,i,dx,sq,d,n;
long int left,right;
while(1)
{
    if(p>q) 
    {
        if(flag==0) printf("INVALID RANGE");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
    d=0,dx=0;;
    n=p;
    while(n>0){
    d+=1;
    n=n/10;
    }
    sq=p*p;
    while(sq>0){
        dx+=1;
        sq=sq/10;
    }
    sq=p*p;
    char str[dx];
    cpy=dx-1;
    while(sq>0){
        str[cpy--]=(sq%10)+48;
        sq=sq/10;
    }
    left=0,right=0;
    for(i=0;i<dx-d;i++)
    {
        left+=(str[i]-48)*pow(10,dx-d-1-i);
    }
    char r[d];
    int k=0;
    for(i=dx-d;i<dx;i++)
    {
        r[k++]=str[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        right+=(r[i]-48)*pow(10,d-1-i);
    }
    if(left+right==p) 
    {
        printf("%d ",p);
        flag=1;
    }
    p+=1;
    }
}}
```

This logic fails for 1/7 of test cases in such a way that it misses out printing a few kaprekar numbers in the range and prints the rest alone. It will be of great help if someone corrects this piece of code. TIA

Comment: Watch out for inexact values when using `pow()` in an integer setting. Better to find a solution that doesn't need `pow()`. Also `if(left+right==p)` is comparing different types where `left+right` might be larger than `INT_MAX`. Also `sq=p*p;` can overflow `int` (you don't show the input ranges).

Comment: Integer overflow seems like the most probable reason

Comment: @WeatherVane the following is the constraint attached with the actual question(sorry that I missed out)
0<p<q<100000

Comment: So `99999 * 99999 = 9999800001` which overflows 32-bit `int`. Also I suggest using `round(pow(...))`

Comment: @WeatherVane do you mean replacing `pow()` with `round(pow())`?

Comment: Better not to use `pow()` at all. Get your powers of `10` from a look-up table.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hey I found this in the discussion portal of the problem which worked too. 
```long sq=(long)p*p; //instead of sq=p*p```